# how to move inputView above keyboard when scrolling the table

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have a view controller in which it has 
 table view and textView below the table

When I tap on the textView the keyboard appears and when I tap outside the textView the keyboard disappar
That works fine but I have one problem which is when I **Drag**(scroll Down) the table view the textView doesn't move down with the keyboard and I see black background behind the keyboard as in the below image

[image: keyboard disappear with textview]

How to solve this problem in Swift

**Update:**
This is my current code that observe the keyboardFrameChanges

```
func keyboardFrameChanged(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict = NSDictionary(dictionary: notification.userInfo!)
    let keyboardValue = dict.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let bottomDistance = mainScreenSize().height - keyboardValue.CGRectValue().origin.y
     let duration = Double(dict.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey) as! NSNumber)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, animations: {
        self.inputViewConstraint!.constant = -bottomDistance
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in
            self.chatTableView.scrollToBottom(animation: true)
    })

}
```

**Update 2:**
I found a solution by changing the keyboardDismissMode from **Interactive** to **OnDrag**

```
chatTableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag
```

This will move the keyboard and the textView immediatly to down once it observe any drag movement in the table  , But how to do it in the **Interactive** mode like in the whatsapp chat view

Answer (score 4):

1. set you scroll view (UITableView or UICollectionView) frame equal to you UIViewController frame
2. set `.interactive` to `keyboardDismissMode` of you scroll view
3. override `canBecomeFirstResponder` and return `true`
4. setup input container with UITextField or UITextView in screen bottom
5. override `inputAccessoryView` and return input container
6. enjoy

See my simple code [here on github](https://github.com/romdevios/simpleInteractiveKeyboardDismiss/blob/master/Test%20chat/ViewController.swift)

## If you implement your own bottom constraint for input view

And change its constant on the keyboard frame notifications. Using these lines of code, the error of predictive bar layout at the end of the animation will be fixed.

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return UIView()
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Best answer, very helpful with the sample project, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Finding the answer for this took forever but this is the correct way of implementing this feature with the interactive state enabled.

In your view controller that has the tableview or collection view displaying chat bubbles override inputAccessoryView, then return the view that contains the uitextView or uitextField. and override canBecomeFirstResponder then return true.

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    get {
        self.inputBar.frame.size.height = self.barHeight // 50.0
        self.inputBar.clipsToBounds = true
        return self.inputBar
    }
}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could observe the frame of the keyboard using the `NSNotificationCenter` and create a method which will be called when the frame changes. In this method you get the coordinates of the keyboard and can reposition your `inputView` accordingly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardDidChangeFrame(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardDidChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardScreenFrameEnd = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    let keyboardViewFrameEnd = view.convertRect(keyboardScreenEndFrame, fromView: view.window)

    let keyboardHeight = keyboardViewFrameEnd.height

    // calculate the offset of your inputView
    inputView.frame = CGRectOffset(inputView?.frame, ..., ...)
}
```

Comment: I'm very beginner to swift, can you explain in more details please