# How do I move my custom view with keyboard interactive hiding?

Tags: ios, scroll, keyboard

I have my tableview set to hide the keyboard interactively. This works beautifully. The user pulls down on my tableview and when the finger hits the keyboard, it moves down with the finger.

However I have a custom view for text entry that I would like to interactively move as the user drags down.

I tried using `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame`, `UIKeyboardWillHide`, and `UIKeyboardDidHide` notifications, but they aren't called repeatedly as the keyboard is pulled down.

I can't just use the tableView scroll offset, because it depends on the contact point of the finger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not just use https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124676/1214800?

Comment: @brandonscript, no. Because that's only called once as the keyboard is shown or hidden. As the user moves the keyboard quickly or slowly or even stops, I want my custom view to move with that finger. Like the text input view of the Messages app. I tweaked the question to show I tried those notifications.

Comment: I believe those methods are called even when you're moving the keyboard interactively?

Comment: @brandonscript, I wish they were. 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32387337/1214800 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059637/1214800 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/39209543/1214800? Definitely going to be a KVO solution.